# How to present paper sketches to a remote client?

Tags: client, presentation, sketching, paper

My process, at the very start, usually involves loads of back and forth feedback because I rather show the client something as soon as possible to see if I'm going in the right direction and like that not wasting much time.  That's why I'm not happy having to redo my sketches in digital form to present the client because I feel it defeats the purpose of doing something quick to get feedback. However a lot of people say they prefer doing that and I also feel a bit awkward to send scanned paper sketches.

So my questions are.
1. Is it ok to present scanned paper sketches?
2. If so how 'beautiful' they must look? Trace it with a black pen? photoshop it?

Comment: Apps like Balsamiq is a good way to present something that is in digital form but also allows you not to dwell on the details too much so you can get quick feedback.

Comment: That's a good tip Aprillion, although i would need to acquire a whiteboard. Hopefully there is something portable I can find.

Comment: posted as answer and deleted the comment ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ask your clients up front
2. make sure they "look natural" - not all gray, not total saturation, ... photos of a whiteboard usually look better than photos of a paper sketch

Answer (score 5):

If you are doing paper mock ups and testing; you can take some images and try to show paths.

Try to document your design process while paper prototyping. There are some free apps for that, check POP if you have a IOS device.

[image: example]

Other than that, scanning is also fine, it will take longer time in my opinion.

Gifs are also working really good if designs are not complicated and long.

Answer (score 4):

As Michael Lai has mentioned in a comment there are tools for rapid prototyping as Balsamiq Mockups, Webzap, Axure, etc which let you make a fast and simple prototyping without losing time and energy.

Also they save the energy of thinking "is it well sketched? is it too messy? what if I have to change a little thing, should I add it in Photoshop or by hand?" etc.

It also tends to be more professional and clear, especially if the person who is going to evaluate it is not too much into design.

Comment: +1 - I have seen quite a few job requirements state "Skills in rapid prototyping in using applications such as Balsamiq" so it is well accepted in the industry

Answer (score 3):

I like to go with sketches early on, a few pointers:

1. If you want to present sketches, set that expectation with the client. Tell them why you're presenting sketches (quicker than doing higher fidelity wires) and that eventually you will get to wireframes.
2. Give them the option to go right to wireframes, but of course, this would impact the timeline and budget.
3. To show the sketches, I always take a photo of them with my iPhone and then edit sketches a bit for brightness / contrast to make sure they're readable.
4. Put the sketches into a PDF, or if the client is comfortable with InVision, I would put them into InVision. However honestly if you aren't looking for detailed feedback, you might not need InVision. But the benefit to InVision is that it gets feedback out of email, which I personally LOVE!